# How to add a forward slash before the last letter in a cell in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to add a forward slash before the last letter in a cell in excel
Example  Cat A = CAT/A

Thank you

Comment: *Example Cat A = CAT/A*  --  You removed a space as well .. Is this also desired?  What have you attempted to script within the program?

Comment: Cat A - > CAT/A looks like you also capitalized all letters, and you replaced the blank space with a `/` character - are you replacing blank spaces or adding a character?

Comment: Hello , Sorry for not being clear.  I would like to remove the space and add a forward slash before the last letter on the string that contains a space . I should add all fields are not the same length Example CAT A ,BIG CAT B ,  SMALL CAT C

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Excel formula to get your results. Then if you so choose - hide the column with your source data

if `Cat A` is in cell `A1` enter the following into `B1`

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-1))&"/"&RIGHT(A1,1)
```

The `TRIM(LEFT` selects all of the text excluding the last letter and removes any surrounding spaces. It then adds the forward slash before concatenating on the last letter.

[image: Demo]